# AWS API authentication with Rest API - AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

Tags: c#, vb.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to create a simple C# or VB program to connect to the AWS API and return a JSON string giving EC2 instance data. Instead I get the error *"AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials"*

I've tried connecting in both `Postman` and in a VB program as follows:

```vb
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO

Module Main

    Sub Main()

        Dim result As String = RunQuery("", "https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances")

        Console.WriteLine(result)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub


    Public Function RunQuery(creds As String, url As String, Optional data As String = Nothing) As String

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        request.ContentType = "application/json"
        request.Method = "GET"

        If data IsNot Nothing Then
            Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
                writer.Write(data)
            End Using
        End If

        Dim d As Date = Date.UtcNow
        Dim t As String = Format(d, "yyyyMMdd") & "T" & Format(d, "HHmmss") & "Z"

        request.Headers.Add("X-Amz-Date", t)
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=***MYAPIKEY***/20201216/us-east-2/ec2/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=***MYAPISECRET***")

        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        Dim result As String = String.Empty

        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
            result = reader.ReadToEnd()
        End Using

        Return result

    End Function
End Module
```

The output from postman was

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>37153d9f-c042-4ae3-8a13-06dc3b052afc</RequestID></Response>
```

[image: Postman output]

I wrote the vb based on postmans code:

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("X-Amz-Date", "20201216T092737Z");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=MYAPIKEY/20201216/us-east-2/ec2/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date, Signature=MYAPISIGNATURE");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Similar questions have been asked many times before but the only answers I can see are that the PC clock was wrong, so I've corrected mine such that its within 0.2 seconds of the true internet time.

Also I could not find another similarly simple VB or C# program that successfully connects to EC2, so this thread may help others in future.

I'm wondering if the signature has to be encoded with base64 or some other algorithm ? Otherwise how can I get this working either in postman or in vb/c# ? TIA

Comment: I've realized that the signature is NOT your secret key, and it has to be generated. So I've also knocked up a c# console app based on this program... https://gist.github.com/yvanin/0bdf68c1139ad698519e  and its still returning a 401 ... Failed StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
{
  x-amzn-requestid: 0980c777-22d8-41b2-a805-a41ef96b5673
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2020 11:17:45 GMT
  Server: AmazonEC2
}

Comment: In postman, can you check with `https://iam.amazonaws.com/?Action=ListUsers&Version=2010-05-08` instead of EC2 service?

Comment: The issue may be the server and not the client.  You need to set the environmental variable in the server.  See : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've now got it working in postman, it just needed a different URL and a version.. this one worked. ```https://ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15``` . I've also now got the c# program working, and this will now migrate over to the vb program in the next couple of hours

Comment: Once done I'll post the final vb program on here so others can use it :)

Answer (score 2):

So there were a couple of issues

1. Wrong URL, the correct one was `https://ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15`
2. I assumed that the secret was the signature, it is not.

Here's a complete VB.NET console application that successfully connects to AWS. Sorry its not commented but the code is reasonably obvious and not too long.

```vb
Option Explicit On
Option Compare Text
Option Strict On

Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text

Public Module Program

    Public Sub Main(ByVal args As String())

        If args.Length <> 5 Then
            Throw New Exception("AWS Integration requires 5 parameters: url accessKey secretKey awsRegion awsServiceName")
        End If

        Dim url As String = args(0)             '   "https://ec2.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&Version=2016-11-15"
        Dim accessKey As String = args(1)       ' api key
        Dim secretkey As String = args(2)       ' api secret
        Dim awsRegion As String = args(3)       ' = "us-east-2"
        Dim awsServiceName As String = args(4)  '= "ec2"

        Dim msg As HttpRequestMessage = New HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.[Get], url)
        msg.Headers.Host = msg.RequestUri.Host
        Dim utcNowSaved As DateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        Dim amzLongDate As String = utcNowSaved.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ")
        Dim amzShortDate As String = utcNowSaved.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
        msg.Headers.Add("x-amz-date", amzLongDate)
        Dim canonicalRequest As New StringBuilder
        canonicalRequest.Append(msg.Method.ToString & vbLf)
        canonicalRequest.Append(String.Join("/", msg.RequestUri.AbsolutePath.Split("/"c).Select(AddressOf Uri.EscapeDataString)) & vbLf)
        canonicalRequest.Append(GetCanonicalQueryParams(msg) & vbLf)
        Dim headersToBeSigned As New List(Of String)

        For Each header In msg.Headers.OrderBy(Function(a) a.Key.ToLowerInvariant, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            canonicalRequest.Append(header.Key.ToLowerInvariant)
            canonicalRequest.Append(":")
            canonicalRequest.Append(String.Join(",", header.Value.[Select](Function(s) s.Trim)))
            canonicalRequest.Append(vbLf)
            headersToBeSigned.Add(header.Key.ToLowerInvariant)
        Next

        canonicalRequest.Append(vbLf)
        Dim signedHeaders As String = String.Join(";", headersToBeSigned)
        canonicalRequest.Append(signedHeaders & vbLf)
        canonicalRequest.Append("e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855")
        Dim stringToSign As String = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" & vbLf & amzLongDate & vbLf & amzShortDate & "/" & awsRegion & "/" & awsServiceName & "/aws4_request" & vbLf & Hash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalRequest.ToString))
        Dim dateKey() As Byte = HmacSha256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("AWS4" & secretkey), amzShortDate)
        Dim dateRegionKey() As Byte = HmacSha256(dateKey, awsRegion)
        Dim dateRegionServiceKey() As Byte = HmacSha256(dateRegionKey, awsServiceName)
        Dim signingKey() As Byte = HmacSha256(dateRegionServiceKey, "aws4_request")
        Dim signature As String = ToHexString(HmacSha256(signingKey, stringToSign.ToString))
        Dim credentialScope As String = amzShortDate & "/" & awsRegion & "/" & awsServiceName & "/aws4_request"
        msg.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=" & accessKey & "/" & credentialScope & ", SignedHeaders=" & signedHeaders & ", Signature=" & signature)
        Dim client As HttpClient = New HttpClient
        Dim result As HttpResponseMessage = client.SendAsync(msg).Result

        If result.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
            'Console.WriteLine(result.Headers)
            Dim s As String = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
            Console.WriteLine(s)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine(result.StatusCode & vbCrLf & result.ToString.Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, ""))
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function GetCanonicalQueryParams(ByVal request As HttpRequestMessage) As String
        Dim values = New SortedDictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim querystring = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(request.RequestUri.Query)

        For Each key In querystring.AllKeys

            If key Is Nothing Then
                values.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString(querystring(key)), $"{Uri.EscapeDataString(querystring(key))}=")
            Else
                values.Add(Uri.EscapeDataString(key), $"{Uri.EscapeDataString(key)}={Uri.EscapeDataString(querystring(key))}")
            End If
        Next

        Dim queryParams = values.Select(Function(a) a.Value)
        Return String.Join("&", queryParams)
    End Function

    Public Function Hash(ByVal bytesToHash() As Byte) As String
        Return ToHexString(SHA256.Create.ComputeHash(bytesToHash))
    End Function

    Private Function ToHexString(ByVal array As IReadOnlyCollection(Of Byte)) As String
        Dim hex = New StringBuilder(array.Count * 2)

        For Each b In array
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b)
        Next

        Return hex.ToString
    End Function

    Private Function HmacSha256(ByVal key() As Byte, ByVal data As String) As Byte()
        Return New HMACSHA256(key).ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data))
    End Function
End Module
```

HTH someone :)